# $elementMatch or $unwind with AND/Multiple condition with monogDB aggregate

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

```
{
  "_id": 1,
   "user_response": [
    {
      "question_name": "Gender ?",
      "question_numeric_id": 1,
      "question_answer": "Male"
    },
    {
      "question_name": "City ?",
      "question_numeric_id": 2,
      "question_answer": "GJ"
    },
    {
      "question_name": "Country ?",
      "question_numeric_id": 3,
      "question_answer": "India"
    }
  ]
}

{
  "_id": 2,
   "user_response": [
    {
      "question_name": "Gender ?",
      "question_numeric_id": 1,
      "question_answer": "Female"
    },
    {
      "question_name": "State ?",
      "question_numeric_id": 2,
      "question_answer": "GJ"
    },
    {
      "question_name": "Country ?",
      "question_numeric_id": 3,
      "question_answer": "India"
    }
  ]
}

{
  "_id": 3,
   "user_response": [
    {
      "question_name": "Gender ?",
      "question_numeric_id": 1,
      "question_answer": "Male"
    },
    {
      "question_name": "State ?",
      "question_numeric_id": 2,
      "question_answer": "GJ"
    },
    {
      "question_name": "Country ?",
      "question_numeric_id": 3,
      "question_answer": "India"
    }
  ]
}

{
  "_id": 4,
   "user_response": [
    {
      "question_name": "Gender ?",
      "question_numeric_id": 1,
      "question_answer": "Other"
    },
    {
      "question_name": "State ?",
      "question_numeric_id": 2,
      "question_answer": "MP"
    },
    {
      "question_name": "Country ?",
      "question_numeric_id": 3,
      "question_answer": "India"
    }
  ]
}
```

The situation is like I have to condition over Array's multiple fields. For Example where:

question_numeric_id : 1 AND question_answer : Male
AND
question_numeric_id : 2 AND question_answer : MP

**So, The output should be:**

```
{
  "_id": 1,
   "user_response": [
    {
      "question_name": "Gender ?""question_numeric_id": 1,
      "question_answer": "Male"
    },
    {
      "question_name": "City ?""question_numeric_id": 2,
      "question_answer": "GJ"
    },
    {
      "question_name": "Country ?""question_numeric_id": 3,
      "question_answer": "India"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id": 3,
   "user_response": [
    {
      "question_name": "Gender ?""question_numeric_id": 1,
      "question_answer": "Male"
    },
    {
      "question_name": "State ?""question_numeric_id": 2,
      "question_answer": "GJ"
    },
    {
      "question_name": "Country ?""question_numeric_id": 3,
      "question_answer": "India"
    }
  ]
}
```

> I have tried many ways using elementMatch and unwind but didn't get success.
> unwinds and elementMatch working only for the single array element.
> I would really appreciate it if you guys help me with this. Thanks

Note:
**Please give a solution using aggregation.**

Comment: Welcome, Can you please add your try in your question, to improve your experience on SO please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: **question_numeric_id : 1 AND question_answer : Male AND question_numeric_id : 2 AND question_answer : MP**. I think you need to review your output. If you want this filter, the output will not have any document. As **question_numeric_id : 2 AND question_answer : MP** doesn't appear in documents for id 1 & 3.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the `$and` keyword.

For example, in pymongo:

```
data_access['your_collection'].find({
"$and": [
    {"user_response.question_numeric_id": 1},
    {"user_response.question_answer": "Male"},
    {"user_response.question_numeric_id": 2},
    {"user_response.question_answer": "MP"},
]
})
```

Hope the above solution would work for you.